# Firebase Admin Node.js SDK doesn't have firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment. Should I use Firebase JavaScript SDK (Client)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

My app engine is using Firebase Admin Node.js SDK to use Firebase.firestore (and other products). I want to use [firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value) to implement a counter.
But it doesn't seem [Firebase Admin Node.js SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore.FieldValue) has firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment.

Should I use Firebase Javascript Client SDK for it? If so, I have to use both Firebase Javascript Client SDK and Firebase Admin Node.js SDK. Is it OK?

I am using Node.js 8 and "firebase-admin": "^7.0.0".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`admin.firestore.FieldValue` is just an alias to this type defined in the `@google-cloud/firestore` package: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/1.3.x/FieldValue

So anything available in that type is readily available in `admin.firestore.FieldValue` as well. That includes `increment()`. The documentation is just out of date.

Comment: As well as the TypeScript bindings, which is actually more problematic.

Comment: Thanks, Hiranya Jayathilaka. After updating firebase-admin from 7.0.0 to 7.3.0, I am able to use it. :)